# Selenium and Chrome Console

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We are currently creating a animation product in html5/css. This animation connect to a Node.js server and reply event animations based on the event id sent from node.

Now, for testing purposes, we pass in the event ID to the animation while it is not connected to node.

So for example, we open the Chrome console and enter "test.sendEvent(1024)" which replies event 1024 on the animation.

How can I use Selenium to send this "test.sendEvent(1024)" message through the Console to the animation??

Cheers for any help
Regards
J

Answer (score -1):

What you need is the JavascriptExecutor object, that you can get from the Driver you're currently using.

Se this for more info: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: Thanks for that samuel, have you any links to aid identifying the Console frame?

Comment: I don't think I got what you mean, but if you call "test.sendEvent(1024)" with the JavascriptExecutor it should work exactly the same way its working when called from the Chrome Console.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, Ill give that a go and see where it takes me

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Chrome browser and Java Selenium Webdriver then below is the command which can be used to send command in browser console:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("app.isConnected = true;");
```

`"app.isConnected = true;"` is the console command which I am using to go to *Offline* and then back to *Online*.